# How to get file name(include extension".jpg"or"mp3") while sending a file from device A to B via socket

Tags: java, android, file-transfer, wifi-direct

I have stucked in this question for a long time . I want to send a file from device A to device B . I can successfully send file to B when I have already known the file's extension(".jpg") and just write it in my code as following

```
try {
  ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
  Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
  Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
  Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");

  final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"    
                + context.getPackageName() +"/wifip2pshared-" 
                            + System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg");

  File dirs = new File(f.getParent()); 
  if (!dirs.exists()) 
      dirs.mkdirs(); 
  f.createNewFile(); 

  Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
  InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
  copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
  serverSocket.close();
  server_running = false;
  return f.getAbsolutePath();       
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
  return null;
}
```

The problem is that now I have several types of file(ex:".jpg",".mp3",".txt")
How can I distinguish each file's type and send whole file name include the extension(ex: Bruno Mars-Lazy song.mp3) instead of assign the file name and type in my original code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see in your code `f.getAbsolutePath();` returns full path with extension.

Comment: Hey MAC , my question is that I want to get the file name from device A when I transfer file to device B and create file with the file's name(include extension).If there isn't the file's extension, my transferd file can not saved in right form (ABC instead of ABC.jpg). Therefore I can't open file ABC what should I do?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a contract between you socket client and server regarding a delimiter between the file name and contents. For example you might send the file name followed by a `|` and then the file contents. On the server side, you read till you get the `|` and this is your file name. Then read the contents of the file.

Comment: Hi John B, can you tell me how do I add delimiter between file name and contents ?Could you give me some example? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have some `OutputStream` on the client side. Do. `outputStream.write(myFile.getName().getBytes()); outputStream.write("|".getBytes()); outputStream.write(fileContents);`